# how do I use Rspec to test the contents of a textarea in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am writing a view spec with RSpec and I keep getting this problem.  The test will find textarea but it fails when I try to test the contents.  Any suggestions?

This is the test I am having trouble with.

```
describe "reminders/edit.html.erb" do
  before(:each) do
     @reminder = Factory(:reminder)
  end

  it "should render the form to edit a reminder" do
      assign :reminder, @reminder
      render
      rendered.should have_selector("form", :method => "post", :action => reminder_path(@reminder) ) do |f|
         f.should have_selector("input", :type => "text", :name => "reminder[title]", :value => "The Title"  )
         f.should have_selector("textarea", :name => "reminder[content]", :value => 'The big content')
         f.should have_selector("input", :type => "submit")
      end

end
```

I might be doing this all wrong since I am pretty new at TDD, but I am seeing that this test passes when I remove the value from the textarea which really confuses me.  So is there a way to test a textarea for it's contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Textareas are different to input elements because their 'value' is their content rather than their value attribute, so should you be matching on the content instead? Try this:

```
f.should have_selector("textarea", :name => "reminder[content]", :content => 'The big content')
```

Comment: Thanks, hat worked perfectly!  And it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I think `:content` should now be `:text`

Comment: or content can be :exact_text if you check the complete value